# how update home screen widget every day

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I want to make my home screen widget updates once every day (at 24:00). 
Should I use a service, or is there another way?

I want to conserve battery charge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the update interval in WidgetProviderInfo to one day, but then you have no influence on the time the update is running.

Easiest way is to set the update interval to every hour and read in `onUpdate` the current time. You ensure this way that your process runs at least between 0 and 1 am.

A Service makes sence if your process runs long and should therefore stay away from the UI Thread.

Comment: I already made it to update every 30 minutes
is that good for battery usage?

Comment: The less the better. More important is what you do in air (WiFi, phone, ...) because everything you do there will keep that Battary busy for two minutes. 30 minutes or 60 minutes do nit make that much difference. What is not possible is a kind of crontab. Android is a kind of Linux but the typical linux services like crontab are not open for usage for Apps. At least not officially.